# How to force downgrade of packages on Ubuntu (Karmic)?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, packages

After doing an update on a bunch of pulseaudio packages my microphone stopped working. It's fine, after all Karmic is still in Alpha. I have reported the bug to launchpad.

In the meanwhile I would like to revert the update of the pulseaudio packages. Unfortunately, none of the packages let me select the "Force Version" option on Synaptic. I thought of removing them and then install the old packages, however removing pulse means removing the package called ubuntu-desktop which I am afraid might mess up things even more. I had a hard time finding the older versions of the packages but I finally downloaded each one of the *.deb's onto my machine.

These are the updates according to the history in Synaptic.

```
libpulse-browse0 (1:0.9.15-4ubuntu3) to 1:0.9.16~test4-0ubuntu1
libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (1:0.9.15-4ubuntu3) to 1:0.9.16~test4-0ubuntu1
libpulse0 (1:0.9.15-4ubuntu3) to 1:0.9.16~test4-0ubuntu1
pulseaudio (1:0.9.15-4ubuntu3) to 1:0.9.16~test4-0ubuntu1
pulseaudio-esound-compat (1:0.9.15-4ubuntu3) to 1:0.9.16~test4-0ubuntu1
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (1:0.9.15-4ubuntu3) to 1:0.9.16~test4-0ubuntu1
pulseaudio-module-gconf (1:0.9.15-4ubuntu3) to 1:0.9.16~test4-0ubuntu1
pulseaudio-module-x11 (1:0.9.15-4ubuntu3) to 1:0.9.16~test4-0ubuntu1
pulseaudio-module-zeroconf (1:0.9.15-4ubuntu3) to 1:0.9.16~test4-0ubuntu1
pulseaudio-utils (1:0.9.15-4ubuntu3) to 1:0.9.16~test4-0ubuntu1
pulseaudio-module-udev (1:0.9.16~test4-0ubuntu1)
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

If you are not afraid do get your hands dirty, the best way to do this is :

> apt-cache show packagename

It will show you all the different version of the package that you can install, according to your sources.list definition. You will get something like that ( this is how it looks for me ):

```
root@shiny-desktop:/home/shiny# apt-cache show libpulse-browse0
Package: libpulse-browse0
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: sound
Installed-Size: 100
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: i386
Source: pulseaudio
Version: 1:0.9.15-4ubuntu2~ppa1
Depends: libavahi-client3 (>= 0.6.16), libavahi-common3 (>= 0.6.16), libc6 (>= 2.4), libcap1, libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.0.2), libgdbm3, libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0), libpulse0 (= 1:0.9.15-4ubuntu2~ppa1), libsm6, libwrap0 (>= 7.6-4~), libx11-6, libxtst6
Description: PulseAudio client libraries (zeroconf support)
 PulseAudio, previously known as Polypaudio, is a sound server for POSIX and
 WIN32 systems. It is a drop in replacement for the ESD sound server with
 much better latency, mixing/re-sampling quality and overall architecture.
 .
 Client libraries used by applications that access a PulseAudio sound server
 via PulseAudio's native interface.
 .
 This package adds support for zeroconf (aka. Avahi, mdns) discovery of
 PulseAudio sinks and sources by client applications.
Homepage: http://www.pulseaudio.org
Original-Maintainer: Pulseaudio maintenance team <pkg-pulseaudio-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>

Package: libpulse-browse0
Priority: optional
Section: sound
Installed-Size: 144
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Pulseaudio maintenance team <pkg-pulseaudio-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Source: pulseaudio
Version: 1:0.9.14-0ubuntu20.2
Depends: libavahi-client3 (>= 0.6.16), libavahi-common3 (>= 0.6.16), libc6 (>= 2.4), libcap2 (>= 2.11), libgdbm3, libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0), libpulse0 (>= 0.9.14), libsm6, libx11-6
Filename: pool/main/p/pulseaudio/libpulse-browse0_0.9.14-0ubuntu20.2_i386.deb
Size: 31522
MD5sum: d7bf325c04432507420551d7c4e04737
SHA1: 537037b6cdcf2e36ab91fff73a543b2bc9a9d2f6
SHA256: 25c9a83f669f3f14b0fdd59141fc048e3053ccdcae5817f338260342ae1164d0
Description: PulseAudio client libraries (zeroconf support)
 PulseAudio, previously known as Polypaudio, is a sound server for POSIX and
 WIN32 systems. It is a drop in replacement for the ESD sound server with
 much better latency, mixing/re-sampling quality and overall architecture.
 .
 Client libraries used by applications that access a PulseAudio sound server
 via PulseAudio's native interface.
 .
 This package adds support for zeroconf (aka. Avahi, mdns) discovery of
 PulseAudio sinks and sources by client applications.
Homepage: http://www.pulseaudio.org
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Task: ubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-dvd-live, edubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-live, mobile-mid, mobile-netbook-remix

Package: libpulse-browse0
Priority: optional
Section: sound
Installed-Size: 144
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Pulseaudio maintenance team <pkg-pulseaudio-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Source: pulseaudio
Version: 1:0.9.14-0ubuntu20
Depends: libavahi-client3 (>= 0.6.16), libavahi-common3 (>= 0.6.16), libc6 (>= 2.4), libcap2 (>= 2.11), libgdbm3, libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0), libpulse0 (>= 0.9.14), libsm6, libx11-6
Filename: pool/main/p/pulseaudio/libpulse-browse0_0.9.14-0ubuntu20_i386.deb
Size: 31516
MD5sum: 63d4937b22f83cff5cc5be101caa3f27
SHA1: bb436fa7bc14eaad31a9f3778f1a887d96e2521d
SHA256: 1f3a5e7a4376c0ee406f30a1c5ec03dc5f484dc059ceb61462516bb728c6c1c5
Description: PulseAudio client libraries (zeroconf support)
 PulseAudio, previously known as Polypaudio, is a sound server for POSIX and
 WIN32 systems. It is a drop in replacement for the ESD sound server with
 much better latency, mixing/re-sampling quality and overall architecture.
 .
 Client libraries used by applications that access a PulseAudio sound server
 via PulseAudio's native interface.
 .
 This package adds support for zeroconf (aka. Avahi, mdns) discovery of
 PulseAudio sinks and sources by client applications.
Homepage: http://www.pulseaudio.org
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Task: ubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-dvd-live, edubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-live, mobile-mid, mobile-netbook-remix
```

Just check on the different version available to you, and then do :

```
apt-get install packagname=version
```

Again as example to the output above :

```
apt-get install ibpulse-browse0=1:0.9.14-0ubuntu20
```

As you can see my pulseaudio is from a ppa on launchpad so if i wanted to downgrade/revert back to the original one supplied by jaunty, i'd do the mentioned above with all the pulseaudio packages that i installed.

Comment: You can also do `apt-cache policy <packagename>`, which will show you only the available versions and their sources, so you get exactly the information you need instead of all the extra stuff that `apt-cache show` provides.

Answer (score 5):

In `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=jaunty
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Then `aptitude install pulseaudio` (and any other packages that won't get automatically downgraded as a dependency).

This may well cause problems down the line (downgrades aren't officially supported or well-tested) but this will at least get the versions down to jaunty ones.

Comment: I do have a directory /etc/apt  but I do not have the file called preferences.

Comment: Sooo... create it then.  Furrfu.

Answer (score 0):

womble is right

You also have to make sure that you have the lines in /etc/apt/sources.list for jaunty.
If you have the correct sources.list lines then you can select the right one from multiple versions.

With pinning you can set the preference what version you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "aptitude", it has a console based user interface. Go to the relevant packages, at the bottom, you'll see available versions. Select the versions you want and press "+" on your keyboard.

There will probably be "broken" packages, you can cycle them with "b" and fix them as you go.